# Expand zone 33X

Tags: coordinate-system, utm

I have coordinates in DDD MM.MMM
Lat N80 45.00
Long E028 55.00

I want to convert these to UTM. Using a web converter i get
35X E534389 N8965867

So far so good. But I have seen these coordinates converted to be within the 33X grid
33X E747460 N8995070

How is this possible?

And how do one even do these kinds of conversions?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the program you are using, you should be able to choose which UTM zone to convert to. If the web converter is detecting the coordinate locations to be within the 35X zone, it's probably going to use that. It wouldn't make sense to use a zone that doesn't actually contain your points.

It definitely seems like one zone would be correct over the other depending on where the coordinates are.  I guess if they are at the border between the two zones than you could just choose one.

Edit: Might help to google about UTM projections if you are unsure about how it works.

Comment: The "original" UTM has 4 wide zones between 72 North and 84 North in latitude band X. Zone 31 is between 0 and 9 East, 33 is between 9 East and 21 East, 35 is between 21 East and 33 East, and 37 is between 33 East and 42 East. So it depends on whether your conversion software is following this convention or not.